# Alinear sticky sidebar a la derecha (jquery)

Tags: jquery

Tengo el siguiente código en el cual básicamente tengo un sticky Sidebar el cual se supone debería estar a la derecha, pero al hacer scroll éste se mueve a la izquierda, ¿de qué propiedad puedo hacer uso para que mi sticky sidebar permanezca siempre a la derecha?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  console.log( "document ready!" );

  var $sticky = $('.sticky');
  var $stickyrStopper = $('.sticky-stopper');
  if (!!$sticky.offset()) { // make sure ".sticky" element exists

    var generalSidebarHeight = $sticky.innerHeight();
    var stickyTop = $sticky.offset().top;
    var stickOffset = 0;
    var stickyStopperPosition = $stickyrStopper.offset().top;
    var stopPoint = stickyStopperPosition - generalSidebarHeight - stickOffset;
    var diff = stopPoint + stickOffset;

    $(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event
      var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns number

      if (stopPoint < windowTop) {
          $sticky.css({ position: 'absolute', top: diff });
      } else if (stickyTop < windowTop+stickOffset) {
          $sticky.css({ position: 'fixed', top: stickOffset });
      } else {
          $sticky.css({position: 'absolute', top: 'initial'});
      }
    });

  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: px;
  position: relative;
}

.header {
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 100px;
}

.sidebar {
  float: right;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background-color: $red
}

.content {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 700px;
}

.footer {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    This is header
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar sticky">
    This is side bar
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    This is main content
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="sticky-stopper"></div>
    This is my footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplmente necesitas hacer uso de la propiedad `right`, en todo caso cuando estes cambiando el **css** con jquery como aquí

```
$sticky.css({ position: 'fixed', top: stickOffset, right: 0 });
```

Agrega un valor a right cómo más te convenga, recuerda que puede obtener una medida en **px**, **rem**, **%**, así como **auto**, **initial** e **inherit**

Comment: te agradezco, no esperaba que fuera tan simple :)